# global.sbt in SBT build tools in windows operating system

Tags: sbt

I am new in SBT build tool. I am currently using windows operating system and I can not find the global.sbt file. Where can I find this configuration file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to sbt.

There's an entry on [Global Settings](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Global-Settings.html) in the reference manual.

> Settings that should be applied to all projects can go in ~/.sbt/0.13/global.sbt

It says `~`, which does not apply to Windows. sbt uses the value of `sys.props("user.home")`, which is same as `System.getProperty("user.home")` in Java.

There's apparently a whole controversy surrounding how [`user.home` is wrong on Windows](http://www.timehat.com/javas-user-home-is-wrong-on-windows/), but should correspond to `C:\Documents and Settings\Foo` on XP, and `C:\Users\Foo` on Windows 7.

Comment: Thank you for your attention Mr Yokota
I want to build this project: https://github.com/cilib/cilib
But I can't